Domain verification for allizom.org in the client id authorized redirect urls for Firefox extensions
In Firefox extensions the identity.getRedirectURL returns a URL like this:
https://[extension_id_hash].extensions.allizom.org
but when I add this URL to the "Authorized redirect URIs" then I get a warning in the "Oauth Overview" that the Domain Verification fails probably because of the domain allizom.org
Note that for Chromium extensions a similar URL is added but with the domain chromiumapp.org and that one passes domain verification, most likely it's whitelisted by Google.
Can we get allizom.org whitelisted or how do we get it verified?

On the oauth consent screen page it will show you how to verify your domain in google search console.  however that will not solve your issue as a redirect uri needs as far as i know cant include subdomain sin that manner.
